# SwiftUI Timeout Alert Warning Then Timed Out

Tags: swiftui, alert, dismiss

I setup a timer to show two alerts. The first alert shows the user a warning that says "Hey, you've been inactive for a while, are you still here" and if they tap yes, then it resets the timer. If they don't tap the alert button, after x amount of time it shows the second alert notifying them their session has expired. They tap OK and it takes them out of the nav view and back to the main page.

This all works perfectly, however XCode is throwing an error of:

```
[Presentation] Attempt to present <SwiftUI.PlatformAlertController: 0x7fc2fa031800> on <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__: 0x7fc2e9f05530> (from <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_24NavigationColumnModifier__: 0x7fc309f28e80>) which is already presenting <SwiftUI.PlatformAlertController: 0x7fc2ea842000>.
```

From what I understand, this is saying, there's already an alert being shown and even though I'm going to dismiss it and show your other alert, I'm going to complain about it, which tells me I'm doing something wrong. I would like to ensure I'm doing it correctly so I do not receive this error in XCode's console.

After creating the timer I am using onReceive to watch it:

```
.onReceive(timer) { time in
            if userTimeout == true {
                timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
            } else {
            caWarning()
            caTimeout()
            }
        }
```

The two functions are really simplistic:

```
func caWarning() {
    if Date.now >= userActivity.addingTimeInterval(5*1) {
        userActivityAlert = true
    }
}

func caTimeout() {
    if Date.now >= userActivity.addingTimeInterval(10*1) {
        userActivityAlert = false
        userTimeout = true
    }
}
```

Finally, my if statement for the alerts is:

```
if userActivityAlert == true {
            VStack {
                EmptyView()
            }
            .alert("Foo", isPresented: $userActivityAlert, actions: {
                Button("I'm Here") {
                    userActivity = Date.now
                }
            }, message: { Text("Are you still there?") }
        ) // End show alert
        } else if UserTimeout == true {
            VStack {
                EmptyView()
            }
            .alert("Foo", isPresented: $userTimeout, actions: {
                Button("OK") {
                    self.caRegExpired.navToHome = true
                }
            }, message: {
                    Text("Your session has expired.\nTap OK, to start over.")
            }) // End Alert
        } // End If
```

I have tried everything I can think of. From `@Environment (\.dismiss) var dismiss` and then calling `dismiss()` (dismisses the underlying view and not the alert), to pouring through Apple's docs and old UIKit stuff (no help).

I'm fine with either doing it this way (i.e. two separate alerts) OR being able to modify the first alert into the second alert after a certain period of time (perhaps even showing a countdown until the user's session has expired).

Honestly, I'm wondering if it's just log noise because the first alert disappears and the second one displays exactly as it should. Literally this all works fine, but it's important that errors are addressed and I want to know if I'm doing something wrong.

This is for the latest SwiftUI 5+ and XCode for iOS 15+

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the alert triggering out of order if value is not updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70312380/why-is-the-alert-triggering-out-of-order-if-value-is-not-updated)

Comment: Unfortunately that has nothing to do with my question. My alert variables are being set just fine and the alerts display in the correct order. As I stated, everything works just fine but I am receiving the console error that I am trying to get rid of. As I mentioned, I believe it's because the first alert is not being dismissed before the second alert shows (even though it the first disappears before the second is shown).

Comment: Share the alert instead of having 2. 2 in a view is problematic but you would probably get better results of you get rid of the `AnyView` Apple discourages its use.

Comment: How do I share the alert when it depends on two separate variables being true or false, and two separate conditions? Not too mention that they are two separate alert messages with two separate actions. Btw, I did try modifying your example code in your other post but I received the same error, except this time I got it quite a few times instead of just once.

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@loremipsum's link has the answer: just wait a little between deactivating the first alert and showing the second:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    @State private var userActivityAlert = false
    @State private var userTimeout = false
    @State private var userActivity = Date.now
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .alert("Foo", isPresented: $userActivityAlert, actions: {
                    Button("I'm Here") {
                        userActivity = Date.now
                    }
                }, message: { Text("Are you still there?") }
                ) // End show alert
            
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .alert("Foo", isPresented: $userTimeout, actions: {
                    Button("OK") {
                        //                        self.caRegExpired.navToHome = true
                    }
                }, message: {
                    Text("Your session has expired.\nTap OK, to start over.")
                }) // End Alert
            
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { time in
            if userTimeout == true {
                timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
            } else {
                caWarning()
                caTimeout()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func caWarning() {
        if Date.now >= userActivity.addingTimeInterval(5*1) {
            userActivityAlert = true
        }
    }
    
    func caTimeout() {
        if Date.now >= userActivity.addingTimeInterval(10*1) {
            userActivityAlert = false
            
            //This delay leaves a little gap between alerts
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                userTimeout = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup. That was it. The dispatchqueue was the only thing I was missing. Now there's no more error in console. Thank you so much!