# Why I am not able to use multiple `.alert` dialog in my SwiftUI project?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to delete list items and when I delete list items, it will show confirmation dialog like `.alert` dialog. I have code below and if I want to remove list item `.alert` dialog is work, but if I try to remove all list items, `.alert` dialog not work, and I am not able to remove all items, I do not know where I missed? I guess most probably it is due to the I have two `.alert` dialog and they are conflicted,  any idea?

```
 struct CustomView: View {

    @State private var selectedUsers: CustomModel?
    @State var users: [CustomModel]
    @State private var selectDelete = false
    @State private var selectAllDelete = false

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {  
            VStack(content: {
                ForEach(users){ user in
                    CustomRowView(user: user)
                        .contextMenu {
                            Button(action: {

                            selectDelete = true

                            }) {
                                Text("remove") 
                            }
                     Button(action: {
                           selectAllDelete = true
                            }) {
                                Text("remove all") 
                            }
                        }
                       
                        .alert(isPresented: $selectDelete) {
                            Alert(title: Text("title"),
                                message: Text("message"),
                                primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {
                                      self.delete(item: data)
                                },
                                secondaryButton: .cancel()
                            )
                        }
                       .alert(isPresented: $selectAllDelete) {
                            Alert(title: Text("title"),
                                message: Text("message"),
                                primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {
                                           self.datas.removeAll()
                                },
                                secondaryButton: .cancel()
                            )
                         }
                        .onDelete { (indexSet) in
                            self.users.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                        }
                 }
            })
        })
    }

    private func delete(item user: CustomModel) {
        if let index = users.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == user.id }) {
            users.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

**model:**

```
struct CustomModel: Identifiable{
var id = UUID().uuidString
var name: String
}

var users = [

CustomModel(name: "david"),
CustomModel(name: "marry"),
CustomModel(name: "henry"),
CustomModel(name: "nadi"), ]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the alert triggering out of order if value is not updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70312380/why-is-the-alert-triggering-out-of-order-if-value-is-not-updated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an alert type and handle it using switch statement.

```
enum AlertType {
    case selectDelete
    case selectAllDelete
}

private var alertType: AlertType?
@State private var isAlertPresented = false
```

...

```
Button(action: {
    alertType = .selectDelete
    isAlertPresented = true
}) {
    Text("remove all") 
}
```

...

```
.alert(isPresented: $isAlertPresented) {
    presentAlert()
}
```

...

```
func presentAlert() -> Alert {
    switch alertType {
    case .selectDelete:
        return Alert(title: Text("title"), 
            message: Text("message"),
            primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {
                self.delete(item: data)
            },
            secondaryButton: .cancel())
    case .selectAllDelete:
        return Alert(title: Text("title"), 
            message: Text("message"), 
            primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {
                self.datas.removeAll()
            },
            secondaryButton: .cancel())
    default:
        return Alert(title: Text(""))
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you apply the modifier to each `Button` it'll work. Also, you might find [confirmationDialog](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/confirmationdialog(_:ispresented:titlevisibility:presenting:actions:)-9ibgk) more suitable for this task.

Move your Buttons into custom Views will help too because body has a 10 View limit.

Comment: it is the same,  I tried

Comment: You can only use one `.alert` per view hierarchy, but you can put them on different levels of your view: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-show-multiple-alerts-in-a-single-view

Comment: @malhal, inside of the .context menu .alert dialog not not work, how can I move into custom views?